# Accessing data from buffer created from boost

Tags: c++, vector, boost, buffer

I am trying to access the data that is serialized using boost buffer function and would like to fill it into two vectors. I am having problem with address to fill the second vector. Following class shows the two vectors and how they are filled.

```
class LidarMeasurement {
  private:
    std::vector<uint32_t> _header;
    std::vector<float> _azimuth;

  public:

    //The header consists of an array of uint32_t's in the following layout
    enum Index : size_t {
         HorizontalAngle,
         ChannelCount,
         SIZE
         };

    explicit LidarMeasurement(uint32_t NumOfChannels = 0u): _header(Index::SIZE + NumOfChannels, 0u) {
        _header[Index::ChannelCount] = NumOfChannels;
    }

    // called before filling vectors
    void Reset(uint32_t total_point_count) {
        std::memset(_header.data() + Index::SIZE, 0, sizeof(uint32_t) * GetChannelCount());
        _azimuth.clear();
        _azimuth.reserve(total_point_count);
    }

    // after reset,Write point function starts filling vectors.. following function is called 104 times (not constant) before next reset
    void WritePoint(uint32_t channel, float angle_hor) {
        _header[Index::SIZE + channel] += 1u;
        _azimuth.emplace_back(angle_hor);
    }

    uint32_t GetChannelCount() const {
       return _header[Index::ChannelCount];
    }
}
```

Once they are filled, its serialized and sent to a client. its serialized using the function below:

```
template <typename Sensor>
  inline Buffer LidarSerializer::Serialize(
      const Sensor &,
      const LidarMeasurement &measurement,
      Buffer &&output) {
    std::array<boost::asio::const_buffer, 2u> seq = {
        boost::asio::buffer(measurement._header),
        boost::asio::buffer(measurement._azimuth)};
    output.copy_from(seq);
    return std::move(output);
  }
```

Once I receive the serialized data, I need to put azimuth back to vector.
I am using the following function to get the vector. `_begin` is the address to the buffer.

```
std::vector<float> GetAzimuth(const uint32_t* _begin) const{
      std::vector<float> localAzimuthMemCopy;
      begin_azi = const_cast<float*>(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(_begin )) + (sizeof(uint32_t) * (GetChannelCount() + Index::SIZE));
      end_azi = begin_azi + GetTotalPointCount();//Total point count is the addition of individual channel point counts (not shown here)
      for(float* i = begin_azi; i < end_azi; i++){
        localAzimuthMemCopy.emplace_back(*i);
      }
      return localAzimuthMemCopy;
    }
```

However, the result i get has a memory offset. I am getting 104 values but the last 18 values are junk. vector is read from a wrong start address. What is wrong with the code?

[image]

Comment: I changed it to "NumOfChannels" avoid confusion..!

Comment: I'm not really familiar with pointer arithmetic magic, but I'm confused with `reinterpret_cast<const float*>(_begin )) + (sizeof(uint32_t) * (GetChannelCount() + Index::SIZE))` You first convert a pointer to uint32_t into a pointer to float, and afterwards trying to advance bytes of ints. Does it work well at this point? As far as I remember, pointer addition requires same type, so here you shoulf first advance the adress at the end of an int array, and then cast a pointer to float.

Comment: `uint32_t OFFSET = sizeof(uint32_t) * (GetChannelCount() + LidarMeasurement::Index::SIZE);
      begin_azi = const_cast<float*>(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(_begin + OFFSET));` Even this does not work

Comment: And what is GetTotalPointCount()? Is it's return value bigger or equal to 104 when you are trying to call GetAzimuth ?

Comment: Returning back to pointer arithmetic magic. You shouldn't really show the compiler how many bytes is occupied by an element, so multiplication number of elements at sizeof(uint32_t) is unnecessary. Compiler should deduct it just by the type of an element and the number of elements. `begin_azi = const_cast<float*>(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(_begin + GetChannelCount() + LidarMeasurement::Index::SIZE));
` Please, let me know if this comment was more usefull.

Comment: Thank you so much... It works like a charm... But could you tell me why it doesn't work or take 18 junk values if I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused bt wrong begin adress calculation.

`begin_azi = const_cast<float*>(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(_begin )) + (sizeof(uint32_t) * (GetChannelCount() + Index::SIZE));`

1) Pointer arithmetic requires only the pointer and number of elements to advance. Number of bytes the compiler should deduct by himself, based on the pointers type. So multiplication at `sizeof(uint32_t)` is redundant. The correct way of pointer advance is shown at `float* end_azi = begin_azi + GetTotalPointCount();`

2) Adress offset should be calculated for *pointer to uint32_t* type, and only then converted to *pointer to float* type.

So correct way of `begin_azi` should look this way:

`begin_azi = const_cast<float*>(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(_begin + GetChannelCount() + Index::SIZE));`

Why did it partially worked earlier? from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Pointer_arithmetic)

> Pointer arithmetic
>
> If the pointer P points at an element of an array with index I, then
>
> - P+N and N+P are pointers that point at an element of the same array with index I+N
> - P-N is a pointer that points at an element of the same array with index {tt|I-N}}
>
> The behavior is defined only if both the original pointer and the result pointer are pointing at elements of the same array or **one past the end** of that array.

Noone knows where did the pointed `begin_azi` pointed after wrong calculation. So noone guarantee that the program will execute in correct or wrong way.

Comment: P.S. as I told in my comment to the question, I'm not really familiar with such manipulations, but I hope they should work this way.